# CRON Job Not Processing

Tags: python, cron

So, I have a CRON job that is simply not working.
For a while (about 5 hours), there was an error in the script myapp.py, because of a password change.

During this time, CRON (understandably) spammed my inbox to death with the same failure notice about 300 times.
So, I fixed the script and turned the CRON job off (read: commented it out) for a few hours, so that it could finish sending out any unsent emails and generally cool off.
However, about 8 hours later, I find that it spammed me another 200-300 emails, and didn't actually stop running when I killed it.
So I deleted all of those emails and uncommented the CRON job, hoping that it would run properly, now that I fixed the script.

Now, however, it doesn't seem to be running at all. No emails are coming in, and nothing is being processed. My hosting provider did a quick check on CRON, and found that other jobs worked without issues.

Here is the crontab I've been operating with:

```
# canary
MAILTO="pcperini@aim.com"
*/1 * * * * /var/chroot/home/content/11/1234567/html/cron/app/myapp.py
```

The python script begins with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
```

which is the path returned by "which python" for the environment. The script has also been chmoded with +x, and runs (correctly) when called (i.e. ./myapp.py)

Comment: search here on SO about crontab, there are A LOT of post regarding debugging of crontab-issues.

Comment: you could do something like `/bin/touch /tmp/i-am-alive` inside your script to disentangle whether it's the mail which is not working or whether the script does not run.

Also, check sending mail interactively works (from the command line) just in case somebody blacklisted this machine as generating too many mails.

Comment: Are you running `crontab /path/to/crontab_file` after commenting/uncommenting lines in `crontab_file`? The crontab is not updated until you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. For whatever reason, my hosting service requires the command to be wrapped in quotes.

```
# canary
MAILTO="pcperini@aim.com"
# 1 myapp
* * * * * "$HOME/html/cron/app/myapp.py"
```